# seekbarpreference library com.yokkomi:seekbar-preference:1.0 return default value

Tags: java, android, github

Hello friends i am using seekbarpefernce library  "com.yokkomi:seekbar-preference:1.0 "  in my project the problem is that when i try to get value from this seekbar its always give me default value which i set in getting value from sharedperfernce  please help me how to get the seekbar value when its changed here is my code geting sharedperfe value inside speakout method please look below speakout method in my code!

library link here:https://github.com/ghkim3221/SeekBarPreference
My perfernce sacreen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="autospeak"
        android:title="Auto Speak"
        android:summary="Turn on/off auto verse read"/>
    <com.yokkomi.commons.preference.seekbar.SeekBarPreference
        android:defaultValue="11"
        android:dialogTitle="Verse Reading Speed"
        android:key="versespeed"
        android:summary="Adjust verse reading speed"
        android:title="Verse Speed"
        app:explain="Drag it left or right"
        app:maxValue="20"
        app:padding="3"/>
    <com.yokkomi.commons.preference.seekbar.SeekBarPreference
        android:defaultValue="8"
        android:dialogTitle="Voice Picth Settings"
        android:key="voicepitch"
        android:summary="Adjust verse reading pitch"
        android:title="Voice Pitch"
        app:explain="Drag it left or right"
        app:maxValue="20"
        app:padding="3"/>
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="switchmode"
        android:title="Turn on Dark Mode"
        android:summary="Reading in night mode"/>




package bible.swordof.God;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.yokkomi.commons.preference.seekbar.SeekBarPreference;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty;

public class ALLVERSE extends AppCompatActivity  implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    private ListView mylistview;
    private ArrayList<String>versenumber;
    private ArrayList<String>verselist;
    private ArrayList<String>id;
    private  ArrayList<String>refernce;
    private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private int booknumber;
    private  int chapternumber;
    private  String bookname;
    public   int versepos;
    private TextView booknametitle;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    int result;
    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;


    private  FullverseAdopter fullverseAdopter;
 RelativeLayout linearLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (textToSpeech!= null) {
            textToSpeech.stop();
            textToSpeech.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();

    }


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_allverse);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        booknametitle = findViewById(R.id.bookname);

        linearLayout=findViewById(R.id.color);
        final Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        booknumber = mIntent.getIntExtra("Boooknumber", 0);
        chapternumber = mIntent.getIntExtra("Chapternumber", 0);
        bookname = mIntent.getStringExtra("Bookname");
        versepos=mIntent.getIntExtra("versenumber",1);



        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=this.getSharedPreferences("DATA",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("versenumber",versepos);
        editor.commit();




        booknametitle.setText(bookname.toString() + "   " + chapternumber);





        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        toolbar.setTitle("ALL VERSE");


        textToSpeech=new TextToSpeech(this,this);









        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        setData();

        mylistview = findViewById(R.id.mylistview);


        BaseAdapter baseAdapter = new BaseAdopter(this, versenumber, id, verselist, refernce);


        mylistview.setAdapter(baseAdapter);



        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(DefaultSettings.autospeak(ALLVERSE.this)){
                    speakOut(verselist.get(versepos-1));
                }
               //speak after 1000ms
            }
        }, 1000);

mylistview.setSelection(Integer.valueOf(versepos)-1);








    }












    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle arrow click here
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }




    private void setData() {
        versenumber=new ArrayList<>();
        verselist=new ArrayList<>();
        refernce=new ArrayList<>();
        id=new ArrayList<>();

        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mDb = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT id, v, t from t_kjv where b="+booknumber+" AND c="+chapternumber+";", new String[]{});
        if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
        { if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                id.add(cursor.getString(0));
                versenumber.add(cursor.getString(1));
                verselist.add(cursor.getString(2));

                refernce.add(bookname+" "+chapternumber);

            }

            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        Fragment fragment;
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.home) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.favoruite)
        { Intent intent=new Intent(this,Favourite.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }  else if (id == R.id.setting) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

// here is getingperfernces always return 11 which i set as default value

```
 private void speakOut(String text) {

        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("versespeed",MODE_PRIVATE);
        float speed=(float)sharedPreferences.getInt("versespeed",11)/50;
        if(speed<0.1)speed=0.1f;

      /*  float pitch=(float)sharedPreferences.getInt("voicepitch",11)/50;
        if(pitch<0.1)pitch=0.1f;

        textToSpeech.setPitch(pitch);*/
        textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(speed);
        textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);


        Toast.makeText(this, ""+speed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {


        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            // tts.setPitch(5); // set pitch level

            // tts.setSpeechRate(2); // set speech speed rate

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
            } else {

            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of SeekBarPreference.

The SeekBarPreference is currently inoperative and not maintained.
I'm really sorry, and you'd better find another library.